# How to write to an array? It is always empty or at 0

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I'm relatively new to VBA

I think the error is in my syntax.

Bellow is a sub routine im working on. the array "MyArray" is always empty. I've dim'd and redim'd and changed the type and the syntax based on what I've seen online a million times its either always 0 or empty. please help.

```
Sub CostPerTon()

Dim FeedType As String, count#, CostPerTon#

FeedType = "Duck - Comercial - Starter - 1 to 25 Days"

Sheets("Formulations").Activate

count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

i = 1

Dim IngredientCost As Double
Dim MyArray(100) As Variant


Do While i < count + 1

    IngredientCost = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FeedType, Range("1:1048576"), i + 2, 0) _
     * Worksheets("Costs").Cells(i + 2, 2) * (1 / 1000)
    MyArray(i) = IngredientCost

    i = i + 1


Loop


End Sub
```

the variable "IngredientCost" has values when I cycle through the loop so that function is fine. It breaks down at the MyArray(i)=IngredientCost line. it just stays empty

and the count is 14

Comment: Have you stepped through the code?  Vlookup can return an error if not found.  It looks from your code, that you just wish to get 12 columns of the row where `Duck - Comercial - Starter - 1 to 25 Days`  This would already be an array, so maybe use `match` then resize the range and take that.

Comment: I have stepped through the code. Everything works fine except the MyArray(i)=IngredientCost line. The Vlookup works fine. @Nathan_Sav

Comment: So what is the value of `ingredientcost` in loop 1?

Comment: It's a single value that changes on every loop. I want that value recorded in an array. on the first loop its a number 1725

Comment: Have you checked your calculation? Why are you looking up across `Range("1:1048576")`?

Comment: Because the number of columns could change to i selected the entire sheet. The thing is the ingredientcost equation works fine. its writing that value to the array that stops working.

Comment: How are you looking at your array following the loop?

Comment: i step through and see that regardless of the loop iteration the array reads as either 0 or empty

Comment: Look at the case i=1 and work out the constituent elements of your calculation. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: I have SJR. Everything seems fine to me and all the variables have the number they should have. But for some reason it will not write to the array... it just remains empty or at a 0 value and I have no clue why

Comment: Just try using `IngredientCost = i` in your loop and report back what happens. Of course your array will have about 86 empty items so perhaps you are looking at them?

Comment: It indeed gives me the number for i. I'm not looking at it visually but i inspect the numbers as i step through the loop. I even set IngredientCost as an array and made it IngredientCost(1) and it worked great. The problem is when I use i. As IngredientCost(i) it fails

Comment: You are counting the number of values in column A but iterating the columns in the vlookup.  That seems a little weird to me.

Comment: Add this before i = i+1  `Debug.Print i, IngredientCost, MyArray(i)`  Do you get the expected output in the Immediate pane?